# pug telmplate does not pass file name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

hi I have this pug code

```
            .form__group
              label.form__label(for='name') Name
              input#name.form__input(type='text', value=`${user.name}`, required, name='name')
            .form__group.ma-bt-md
              label.form__label(for='email') Email address
              input#email.form__input(type='email', value=`${user.email}`, required, name='email')
            .form__group.form__photo-upload
              img.form__user-photo(src=`/img/users/${user.photo}`, alt='User photo')
              input.form__upload(type='file', accept='image/*', id='photo', name='photo')
              label(for='photo') Choose new photo
              
            .form__group.right
              button.btn.btn--small.btn--green Save settings
```

and my API  using multer

and I have in my index.js this to get my the file name to update it.

```
 if (userDataForm)
   
    userDataForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
     
      async function makeGetRequest() {
try{
  const form = new FormData();
         form.append('photo', document.getElementById('photo').files[0]);
        let payload = {name : document.getElementById('name').value, email : document.getElementById('email').value,form };
      
        let res = await axios.patch('/api/v1/users/updateMe', payload);
      
        // let data = res.statusText; 
        // console.log(XMLHttpRequest); 
        showAlert('success', 'Updated'); 
        location.assign(window.location.href); 
      }
      catch (err){
       

       
          let errr=err.response.data; 
          // let g=data.document.querySelector('.error__msg');
          const htmlFile = new DOMParser().parseFromString(errr, 'text/html');
        
          const errorMessage = htmlFile.getElementsByClassName('error__msg')[0].innerText;
        
          console.log(errorMessage)
        
          showAlert('error', errorMessage);  
       
      }
      }
      
     

      makeGetRequest(); 
 

    });
```

to update the photo, but I can not get the name of the photo (undefined) to update it and to pass it to my API.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found an answer and it works fine for me.

```
 if (userDataForm)
   
    userDataForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
     
      async function makeGetRequest() {
try{
  const formd = new FormData();
  let na = formd.append('name', document.getElementById('name').value);
   let em=  formd.append('email', document.getElementById('email').value);  
   let ph=   formd.append('photo', document.getElementById('photo').files[0]);
        
      
        let res = await axios.patch('/api/v1/users/updateMe', formd);
      
        // let data = res.statusText; 
        // console.log(XMLHttpRequest); 
        showAlert('success', 'Updated'); 
        location.assign(window.location.href); 
      }
      catch (err){
       

       
          let errr=err.response.data; 
          // let g=data.document.querySelector('.error__msg');
          const htmlFile = new DOMParser().parseFromString(errr, 'text/html');
        
          const errorMessage = htmlFile.getElementsByClassName('error__msg')[0].innerText;
        
          console.log(errorMessage)
        
          showAlert('error', errorMessage);  
       
      }
      }
      
     

      makeGetRequest(); 
 

    });
```